# Custom GitHub tab with own extension

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, azure-devops, github-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am making an extension for github.
I already created extension for VSTS.

[image]

My goal - write extension that adds some custom tab with own functionality.

[image]

Github guide explains that I can create "github app" that will send to my webhook server all changes that I subscribed them. But nothing about new functionality on their site in difference that VSTS.

I installed extensions of other developers that add this custom tab. But they all required installation of chrome extension.

Do I need to develop chrome extension that adds this tab on github.com pages. 
Or Is there other ways to implement this?

Comment: What's the function of the extension you installed in VSTS? And do you want to achieve the same function with extension on github?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT
It's not so important that I installed it there.
If you mean what kinds of contributors? 
There are several: 
1."type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
2."type": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab",
......

I just want my code to run there.
So in VSTS I know that type "ms.vss-web.hub" adds some tab with my code. 
I want some similar to github. 
But only that I found is webhook service of github

And yes, I want the same